# I got this error "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type

Tags: laravel, insertion

When i try to insert data into my table this error occurs

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portal\vendor\laravel\framew...

#### view

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('notice.store') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Select Group to Post  Notice">Select Group to Post Notice </label>
        <select class="bg-white text-danger  form-control " name='GroupID[]' multiple>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                <option value="{{ $user->GroupID }}">{{ $user->GroupID }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Enter Notice">Enter Notice</label>
        <input class="bg-white text-danger p-2 form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="Notice" placeholder="Enter Notice">
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg px-5" type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

#### controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $member = $request->input('GroupID');

    foreach($member as $value) {
        $storeInfo = new notice();
        $storeInfo->GroupID = $request->input('GroupID');
        $storeInfo->Notice = $request->input('Notice');
        $storeInfo->save();
    }

    return redirect('/notice');
}
```

Comment: If one of the posts below answered your question **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Comment: Just had this error. My solution may not help your case but in case anyone else commits the same error as me, I wanted to cast a json column to array in my Eloquent model and I typed `protected $attributes = ['items' => 'array'];` instead of `protected $casts = ['items' => 'array'];`

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine the reason you're getting this error is because of:

```
$storeInfo->GroupID = $request->input('GroupID');
```

`$request->input('GroupID')` will return an array (`name='GroupID[]'`) and not an individual id.

Since you're already looping through the group ids you can instead use the value for the `GroupId`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->input('GroupID') as $groupId) {
        $storeInfo = new notice();
        $storeInfo->GroupID = $groupId; //<--here
        $storeInfo->Notice = $request->input('Notice');
        $storeInfo->save();
    }

    return redirect('notice');
}
```

Comment: This is what I initially thought, but the error message seems backwards: "must be of the type **array**, **string** given".

Comment: @TimLewis Yeah, I know what you mean! It does seem a little counter-intuitive.

Answer (score -1):

try changing controller logic

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $member=$request->input('GroupID');
    foreach($member as $value){
        $storeInfo = new notice();
        $storeInfo->GroupID = $value;
        $storeInfo->Notice = $request->input('Notice');
        $storeInfo->save();
    }

        return redirect('/notice');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: $storeInfo->GroupID = $value; <-- this changed pass single value instead of array